# php do_pgsql unable initialize module

Tags: php, warnings

In Terminal I typed:

```
php -v
```

and I got this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2016 21:48:49) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

My question is:
Are these warnings important and, if yes, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings indicate that the `pdo_pgsql` extension was compiled against a different (in this case newer) PHP API version than the one you are currently running. If you are not using this extension you can safely ignore these errors and disable the extension, however, if you are you will need to  fund and install a compatible version.

Comment: Thanks! You make my day. I don't use postgresql at all... So, status quo